# How to build and install dlib for python without GUI support?

Tags: python, setup.py, amazon-sagemaker, dlib

#### Background:

I'm running a ‍`jupyter‍` notebook on an AWS `sagemaker` ec2 instance (Which uses Fedora Linux) and one of my requirements is `dlib`.
However, `dlib` (by default) uses `xorg's x11` libs for GUI support, and these are not installed on the `sagemaker` instance. I do not need the GUI support, and `sagemaker` does not support yum installs, so I'm trying to build it without them.

I've cloned `dlib`'s github repo and have attempted to build with `python setup.py`, where it throws x11 errors. I've read through the website and it says that [you can define the `DLIB_NO_GUI_SUPPORT` preprocessor directive to compile without GUI support](http://dlib.net/compile.html). Sounds great! I read through the setup.py file and see that I can add that by running `python setup.py x DLIB_NO_GUI_SUPPORT` where `x` is one of [`--no`, `--set`, `--compiler-flags`, and `-G`].
I don't know which one, so I try them all:

- `python setup.py --no DLIB_NO_GUI_SUPPORT`
- `python setup.py --set DLIB_NO_GUI_SUPPORT`
- `python setup.py --compiler-flags DLIB_NO_GUI_SUPPORT`
- `python setup.py -G DLIB_NO_GUI_SUPPORT`

None of them worked.

#### Question:

What is the correct syntax for setting the `DLIB_NO_GUI_SUPPORT` preprocessor directive for `dlib` using `setup.py`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to build the source first, passing `-D DLIB_NO_GUI_SUPPORT` to cmake. Then you can install the python wrappers as you did.